How to Use Live Chart with .Net 8.0?
I want to use LiveChart graphs in my project. I added LiveChart library from Nuget, but when I try to drag chart control to form window it show gray(disabled). How to solve this problem?
I'm using .net 8.0 and visual studio 2022

Tried to add change .net version, added library description to xaml file

That's .NET Framework only. For .NET, use LiveCharts2 (LiveChartsCore)
